# How Do I Add an Attribute to an Array for a SoapClient Request In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, soap, soap-client

Hi Im quite new to using Soap, but all is going quite well, I have written a script using PHP soap-client, and all is well apart from one tag which has an attribute, and i can figure out a way to pass this in the $params list before the call to the service.

Im building the params like so:- (excert)

```
'Goods' => array(
      'Description' => '$Description','Quantity' => '$qty');
```

however I need the XML to be:-

```
<Goods Type="EGoods">              
           <Description>Test</Description>
           <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Goods>
```

Note the type="EGoods" on the goods tag, how can i modify my array in php to account for this attribute?

When I submit the soap request as is, I get the error saying goods cant be null or empty.

Thanks For any help.

Comment: Can't you just do: `'Goods Type="EGoods"' => array (`

Comment: @Daan no, I get the error of Not Found when I tried that way, and the whole of goods is missing from the outputted xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging around in the manual I managed to find a solution which works :)

```
'Goods' => array('_' => '', 'Type'=>'EGoods',
        'Description' => '$Description', 'Quantity' => '$qty');
```

Produces

```
<Goods Type="EGoods">              
       <Description>Test</Description>
       <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Goods>
```

Solution Found Here [PHP: SoapParam::SoapParam - Manual Comment 114146](http://php.net/manual/en/soapparam.soapparam.php#114146)

I had to slightly modify it to work, if you compare my array structure to that in the original you see what changes I had to make.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = new MessageHeaderSoapStruct;
$var->From    = 'foo';
$var->To      = 'bar';
$var->version = 1;
$namespace = 'http://xxx'; # Namespace of MessageHeader WSDL element
$MessageHeader = new SoapVar($var, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'MessageHeader', $namespace);
```